# python connect to remote host and capture webpage on local host

Tags: python, selenium, subprocess, python-multiprocessing, pyvirtualdisplay

I've had a look around here for multiprocessing, for the most part, I've gotten it narrowed down but the last bit fails for some reason.

**Context**

I have a remote webserver that I connect to that I have port forwarded the HTTP page to a local port. I need to connect to the remote host, while I'm connected, I need to open up the HTTP page on my local machine and capture the page.

**Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import paramiko
import multiprocessing
import time

def grabscreendisplay():
 time.sleep(10)
 print('running display code now... ')
 display = Display(size=(1024, 768), visible=0)
 display.start()
 driver=webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
 URL="http://localhost:9012"
 driver.get(URL)
 screenshot=driver.save_screenshot('my_screenshot.png')
 driver.quit()


def getserver():
    SERV = raw_input('Please enter the server you would like to connect to: ')
    return SERV
def connect_to_server(SERV):
    print(SERV)
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    print('Connecting to ' + SERV)
    ssh.connect(SERV, username='root', key_filename='...')
    connected = True
    print('Connected to ' + SERV)
    time.sleep(30)

def main():
    SERV = getserver()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='p1', target=connect_to_server(SERV))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(name='p2', target=grabscreendisplay())
    p2.start()
    p1.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Problem faced**

The .png just displays a failed connection to the port ('localhost refused to connect')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SSHTunnel**

So I had to research SSH Tunnel which creates a randomly generated local bind port to map the remote destinaton port to.

In short after repeat attempts I managed to get my end result, however if you are seeking an answer to a problem like mine I will provide my code and also an example that hopes to fit all instead of my specific issue

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import paramiko
import time
SSHTunnelForwarder.SSH_TIMEOUT = SSHTunnelForwarder.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 5.0

                     ### Setting up the SSHTunnel ###

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        SERV, #IP of 10.10.10.1
        ssh_username='admin',
        ssh_pkey="...",
        remote_bind_address=(SERV, 80), # map the 10.10.10.1 port 80
        ) as tunnel: 

                     ### preliminary SSH connection ###

        client = paramiko.SSHClient() # set up SSH connection
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(SERV, username='admin', key_filename='...')

             ### Setting up the pyvirtualdisplay on local machine ###

        display = Display(size=(1024, 768), visible=0) # set virtual window size
        display.start()
        driver=webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver') # I'm using Chromedriver
        print(tunnel.local_bind_port) # this prints the randomly generated local port, for example in my case it would be localhost:32842 and would display the web page of the remote host
        time.sleep(5)                    
        URL='http://localhost'+':'+str(tunnel.local_bind_port)
        driver.get(URL)
        time.sleep(10)
        print(driver.title)
        screenshot=driver.get_screenshot_as_file('newscreen.png')
```

**Simplified**

```
 with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        <REMOTE_HOST IP>,
        ssh_username=<ssh_username>,
        ssh_pkey=<location of own private key>,
        remote_bind_address=(<REMOTE_HOST>, <REMOTE_PORT>),
        ) as tunnel: 
        client = paramiko.SSHClient() # set up SSH connection
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(<REMOTE_IP>, username=<ssh_username>, key_filename=<location of own private key>)
        display = Display(size=(1024, 768), visible=0)
        display.start()
        driver=webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
        print(tunnel.local_bind_port)
        while True:
           sleep(30)
           # ctrl + c to stop program
        # Go into own local web browser and enter http://localhost:<local_bind_port> and you should see the web page
```

[Website for Chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/)